# Books on computable analysis

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I stumbled on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634379/formal-definition-of-effective-proof/635192#635192) the other day, and was looking at the top answer. I'd never heard of computable analysis before, but I'm now curious to hear more about it. I've been working on Bishop\Bridge's *Constructive Analysis*, but would really appreciate any book recommendations on computable.

Thanks.

Comment: Google (as separate words, not as a phrase) the three words "computable" "analysis" "Bridges", and google the three words "computable" "analysis" "Weihrauch". Try using "constructive" in place of "computable", also.